# Grid and placing widgets : once again

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, widget

Dears,

Although I want to make it simple, I'm still failing in creating a class of "windows" which by default will have a basic menu (not in code yet), a frame of 10 rows and 10 cls, and in the last cell of this frame (row = 9, col=9) a "Close" button.

Then, I could create several classes that will inherit from that one, and adding more widgets, commands, .. Well very basic

Yes but, although I gave weight to cells,..,... the button is still on the top left corner, and not the bottom right one. What did I miss when managing widgets with .grid()

Thks a lot

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class myWindows(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,
                 pWtitle='',
                 pParent = '',
                 pIsOnTop = False,
                 pWidth=800,
                 pHeight=600,
                 pIsResizable=False,
                 pNbRows = 10,
                 pNbCols = 10): 
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, pWtitle)
        self.geometry('%sx%s' % (pWidth, pHeight))
        if pIsResizable :
            self.minsize(pWidth, pWidth)

        rFrame =tk.Frame(self, borderwidth=1, relief="ridge")


        #to make it simple by default, there will be a grid of 10rows and 10columns
        for r in range(pNbRows) :
            rFrame.grid_rowconfigure(r,weight=1)
        for c in range(pNbCols) :
            rFrame.grid_columnconfigure(c,weight=1)

        rFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ns')

        #all windows will have a quit button on the bottom right corner (last cells)
        #Need deduct 1 in the parameter as indexes start from 0

        bt=ttk.Button(self, text='Close',command=self.quit)
        bt.grid(row=pNbRows -1, column=pNbCols -1, sticky='se')


app = myWindows( pWtitle='MAIN')
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are configuring the weights inside of `rFrame`, but you are putting `rFrame` and the button directly in the root window. You have not configured weights for any rows or columns in the root window.

Answer (score 0):

grid doesn't display rows and columns that don't contain anythng. Try, for example adding one placeholder label with empty picture (Label = (self, image = PhotoImage())) in every row and column of the grid until you populate it with real stuff. Source
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

> minsize= Defines the minimum size for the row. **Note that if a row is
>   completely empty, it will not be displayed, even if this option is
>   set.**

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I came up with a solution :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class myWindows(tk.Tk):
def __init__(self,
             pWtitle='',
             pParent = '',
             pIsOnTop = False,
             pWidth=800,
             pHeight=600,
             pIsResizable=False
             ): 
    tk.Tk.__init__(self)

    tk.Tk.wm_title(self, pWtitle)
    self.geometry('%sx%s' % (pWidth, pHeight))
    if pIsResizable :
        self.minsize(pWidth, pHeight)

    #all windows will have a quit button on the bottom right corner (last cells)
    #Need deduct 1 in the parameter as indexes start from 0

    bt=ttk.Button(self, text='Close',command=self.quit)
    bt.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='se')

    #to make it simple by default, there will be a container on top of button
    rFrame =tk.Frame(self, borderwidth=1, bg = 'blue', relief="ridge")
    rFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)


    #give max weight to the first cell to 
    #make sure the container is filling up the empty space
    #on top of the button(s)
    self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight =0)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight =1)


app = myWindows( pWtitle='MAIN')
app.mainloop()
```